# How to implement WebSocket to communicate with a server that has SSL enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, websocket

I am trying to implement WebSocket communication between a client "web browser" and a Apache 2.4/PHP 5.6 server that is running on Windows 2008 R2.

My application is assume to be running on this URL "HTTPS"
`https://myApllication.example.com`

I am not sure if there is something I need to install on the server before this works or not.

My code so far looks like this

```
$(function(){
    if(!("WebSocket" in window)){

        console.log('your browser does not support WebSocket'); 
    } else {

        connect();

        $('#disconnect').click(function(){
            socket.close();
        });
    }


    function connect(){
            var socket;
            var host = "ws://myApplication.example.com:8000/dev/icws/poll2.php";

            try{
                var socket = new WebSocket(host, {
                    protocolVersion: 13, 
                    origin: 'https://www.example.com'
                });
                message('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState);
                socket.onopen = function(){
                    message('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (open)'); 
                }

                socket.onmessage = function(msg){
                    message('Received: ' + msg.data);                   
                }

                socket.onclose = function(){
                    message('Socket Status: '+ socket.readyState + ' (Closed)');
                }           

            } catch(exception){
                message(exception);
            }
        } //End connect()   

        function message(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }//End message()


    });
```

This code will give me this error in the console.

```
DOMException [SecurityError: "The operation is insecure."
code: 18
nsresult: 0x80530012
```

Here is how my poll2.php script looks like

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream" . PHP_EOL);
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache" . PHP_EOL);

    echo "data: {mykey: 'myvalue', eventName: 'eventName'}" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

** Edited**
After changing the host from

```
var host = "ws://myApplication.example.com:8000/dev/icws/poll2.php";
```

to

```
var host = "wss://myApplication.example.com:8000/dev/icws/poll2.php";
```

I no longer get the security error but I get this in the console.

```
Socket Status: 0 (ready)
Socket Status: 3 (Closed)
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://myApplication.example.com:8000/dev/icws/poll2.php
```

What could be causing the connection not to be made?
Do I have to open the port 8000 on the server?

Comment: You're trying to connecting websockets without TLS. Change `"ws://myApplication.example.com:8000` to `"wss://myApplication.example.com:8000`. There's not enough details in your question (what's the server?) to know if it will be enough (probably not the right port).

Comment: @DenysSéguret  thank you so much I no longer get the error not. but Here what I still get in the console. `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://......` do I have to make amy change to my php script?